# Just-Audio Flutter Headers are not working when adding to playlist (ConcatenatingAudioSource)

Tags: flutter, audio, just-audio

We need to pass headers to server that hosts mp3 files and using following code but somehow header field is showing as null in logs, can you review and let us know if we are missing something or not using the headers correctly:

```
await _player
        .setAudioSource(
      ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children: queue
            .map(
              (item) => AudioSource.uri(
                Uri.parse(item.id),
                headers: {'header1': 'media.Ourhost', 'header2': 'media.Ourhost.app'},
                tag: '',
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Headers should work on playlist items. There is a chance of a proxy key clash if two of your URLs have the same path and query string but a different host. As long as that's not the case, you should expect it to work and you might want to submit a bug report to report that it's not working and get any issue fixed.